# tfidf using cosine similarity for sentence similarity in python

Tags: python-3.x, cosine-similarity, record-linkage, tfidfvectorizer

I need to find Matched pair between source(Input) and Target (database record).
I am using tf-idf with cosine similarity to calculate the matches.

But I am getting less score for correct matched pair even though it has more common words than other, In few other cases I am getting same cosine score for more than 10-12 pair which is highest among all scores

For Example:

```
**source**
S1: FEBCO 905532 1/2 - 1 860-AG METAL

**Target**
T1: febco&reg; 601-m lead free air gap drain for use with 860/lf860 860u/lf860u series 1/2 to 1 in reduced pressure assemblies
.
.
.
.
.
.
Tn: watts radiant&trade; 81008809 tape mat, 13 ft - 4 in l x 3 ft w, 40 sq-ft coverage, 240 vac watts radiant&trade; tape mat, 3 ft width, 13 ft - 4 in length, 40 sq-ft coverage, 240 vac, orange
```

Below is the steps I am following

1. Read Source and Target Data
2. Preprocess source and Target data (to lower case, remove punctuation with words)
3. For each source data
   I have taken one source data and
   concatenate with target data.
   Construct tf-idf matrix for source-target corpus with description in source description as vocabulary

Below is the code

```
def check_similarity(data,vocab):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\S+',vocabulary=set(vocab),lowercase=False)
    print("vectorizer defined:\n")
    tf_idf_matrix  = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['productdescriptionSource_processed'])
  allpair_similarityVector=cosine_similarity(tf_idf_matrix[0,],tf_idf_matrix[1:tf_idf_matrix.shape[0],])
    desired_similarityVector=np.argsort(allpair_similarityVector)
    similarityVector=allpair_similarityVector.shape[1]
    desired_similarityVector=np.argsort(allpair_similarityVector)
    similarityVector=allpair_similarityVector.shape[1]
    matchedtargetindex=desired_similarityVector[0,similarityVector-4:similarityVector-1]
    cosinescore=allpair_similarityVector[0,matchedtargetindex]
    matchedtargetindex=matchedtargetindex+1
    return matchedtargetindex
```

In above code:
   Data: source-target corpus

vocab:words only in source description

The result I got is

**output1:**
For source-target pair
     **source**:FEBCO 905532 1/2 - 1 860-AG METAL
     **Target**:febco® 601-m lead free air gap drain for use with 860/lf860 860u/lf860u series 1/2 to 1 in reduced pressure assemblies

i got cosine score
**0.409562707**
(This is correct pair)

**output2:**
But I got highest cosine score of **0.5** for pair

**source**:FEBCO 905532 1/2 - 1 860-AG METAL
     **Target**:watts radiant™ 81008809 tape mat, 13 ft - 4 in l x 3 ft w, 40 sq-ft coverage, 240 vac watts radiant™ tape mat, 3 ft width, 13 ft - 4 in length, 40 sq-ft coverage, 240 vac, orange

Question:
Is there any other term weight metrics so that I get highest cosine score for correct match pair?